# How to create active sessions with Jmeter before running the load test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to run a load test where I already have 20k active sessions on website and then run a load test to see the performance.

I tried everywhere searching for solution but could not find any specific answer to this.I can run a load test from Jmeter to create that many request but those won't stay on website for long.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Ultimate thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) plugin to create that much load by maintain the duration..let say for 30 min. Then once it is ramp up and maintaining the load you can run another load test. Also check different custom thread group plugins at https://jmeter-plugins.org/

Please check if it helps.